# Optimization using eigenvalue decomposition

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier, matrix-decomposition

Why this optimization problem can be solved to global optimality using eigenvalue decomposition?
The optimization problem is the following:

> \begin{align}
>         &\operatorname*{max}_{q_1 , \space q_2} & & \frac{q_1^{T}X^{T} Y q_2}{\sqrt{(q_1^{T} X^{T}Xq_1)(q_2^{T}Y^{T}Yq_2)}} 
>         & X \in  \mathbb{R}^{m \times n_1} , Y \in  \mathbb{R}^{m \times n_2}, q_1\in \mathbb{R}^{ n_1}, q_2\in \mathbb{R}^{ n_2} 
>  \end{align}

### My thoughts

Turning the optimization to constrained as: 
\begin{align}
        &\operatorname*{max}_{q_1, \space q_2 } & & q_1^T A q_2  
        & where \space  A=X^T Y \\
        &\text{subject to}
        && \|\mathbf{q_1}\| = 1 \space  ,\space \|\mathbf{q_2}\| = 1
        \end{align}

*Taking the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}=q_1Aq_2 -B_1 \|q_1\|-B_2 \|q_2\|$ and then taking the derivative of $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $q_1$ and $q_2$ I got the follwoing: 
\begin{align}
(A-\beta _1 I )q_1=0 \\ 
(A-\beta _2 I )q_2=0
\end{align}
The equation for eigen values of A. I have no idea if this is correct or how to continue.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it all explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation ?

Comment: The reformulation is not correct. It should be $\|\mathbf{q_1} X\| = 1$ and $\|\mathbf{q_2} Y\| = 1$.